# Access DoCmd.OpenForm Not Working

Tags: sql, ms-access

Looking for a second set of eyes to figure out my problem with an Access form filter. I created a search form, when filled in, appends search criteria to a string variable (strQuery) that is put in place to the [WhereCondition] for opening a form. However, when the script is ran, nothing comes up except for a filtered form with no records.

Here is the line that opens the form:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "ADD_NEW_NCMR", , , strQuery
```

Before the line is ran, strQuery equals:

```
1=1 AND [NCMR].[NCMR_NUM] = '12-129'
```

The form name, and table.column combination are all correct. In fact, using the DCount function returns the result of 1, which is correct for this query, and returns the correct number for other queries as well. This makes me think that there is nothing wrong with the where condition.

```
DCount("[NCMR_NUM]", "NCMR", strQuery)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your form's Data Entry property.  You can find it on the Data tab of the form's property sheet.

If Data Entry = Yes, the form will not display existing records.

Sounds like you want Data Entry = No, so that existing records which match your OpenForm WhereCondition will be displayed.

Comment: That complicates things for me... The form I'm using to open up the records that the search is querying for is the same form that was used to create the record.